# Docusign API Sender View with correction

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the Docusign API and programmatically create the envelope and add recipients. The sender is then redirected to the sender view URL, adds initial and signature tags and then sends the envelope. Works great.

The problem is sometimes that once the envelope is SENT, the senders then realize they forget to add these tags for multiple recipient. I can always generate another sender view URL with no problem and redirect the sender. The problem is that it takes them to a sort of "read only" view of the document and they have to click on "OTHER ACTIONS" and then "Correct". From there they can modify the envelope somewhat and the recipients and then click a button that reads "Edit Documents and tags" to get back to the original sender view where you place the signature tags.

Once an envelope is sent, is there any way to correct it like this but SKIPPING this "correction page" and going straight back into the view where you're actually placing the tags? Our web application does all the recipient adding and envelope creation. We don't want our users to be able to have any advanced options and possibly mess up the envelope.

Comment: If there isn't a way to do this, is it possible to modify an envelope's status from SENT to DRAFT? If so, we could do that and then redirect the users to the sender view URL. This would be a great workaround since we suppress all automatic emails to the recipients. When the envelope is sent, the return URL in our application immediately looks at the envelope and checks to see if there are any recipients without tabs. At this point we would hopefully be able to change it back to draft status, warn the user they missed someone, and redirect them back to the sender view before emailing recipients

Comment: Sorry I mean from SENT to "CREATED"

Comment: Once an envelope progresses to status = Sent, you can't revert it back to status = Created.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use createCorrect API call for the sent envelope, API call is

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/correct
```

More details are available at https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createCorrect/

This call will directly open the envelope for editing.

Comment: Apologies. I probably wasn't clear. This "correct view url" takes the user to the page where they can manually review/edit recipients and other envelope information before they click "edit documents and tags". I want to skip this page as well and have the user go DIRECTLY to the same view they would as if they clicked this "edit documents". The way our application is built, we can't have the users editing the envelope documents or recipients manually themselves.... only placing signature tabs like when the envelope is first created and the sender view takes them directly to the tab view

Comment: Please be aware that even within what you're referring to as the "edit documents" view, the user has all capabilities of a sender -- for example, they are able to add/edit/remove recipients from this view. It's just that these types of capabilities aren't as obvious via the "edit documents" UI as they are via the initial "correct envelope" UI.

Comment: Understood. In the  preferences, luckily there were enough advanced options to lock down this screen so despite being able to see all the options, the "sender" won't actually be able to change anything. We managed to get everything greyed out when they get to this URL